# How to use fbgraph in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Two questions:

- How do I get a list of groups a user is in?
- How do I post on a user's wall?

Here's what I have so far:

```
include DeviseOauth2Facebook::FacebookConsumerHelper

client = facebook_client

client.access_token = User.first.facebook_token

fb_user = client.selection.me.info!
```

That seems to work fine, these work as expected:

```
>> fb_user.firstname
=> "Bobby"
>> fb_user.email
=> "bobby.tables@example.com"
```

But from here I'm not really sure what to do.

Also, the example at the fbgraph github page fails:

```
>> client.search.query('q').on('users').limit(20).info
NoMethodError: undefined method `info' for #<FBGraph::Search:0x2b91bd1554f8>
```

/home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150
 /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `call'
 /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:28:in`call'
 /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'

If you can help me identify the user's groups and post on their wall, or point me toward further instruction, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using `info!`you are missing a "!"